# How to add a column vector to an existing table in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

how can I add a column vector that I have created using SELECT (manipulating a column of the existing table) to that existing table?

This is my starting matrix:

```
name    date of Birth
Mark    15/01/1987
John    27/05/1945
Lisa    3/04/1981
```

I create with a SELECT and a function of the date their age:

```
Age
33
74
38
```

How can I create a new table (called table_new) in which I add the new column (Age) to the existing matrix formed by name and date of birth in SQL? As follows:

```
    name    date of Birth   Age
    Mark    15/01/1987   33
    John    27/05/1945   74
    Lisa    3/04/1981    38
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Postgresql <> nosql. I removed these conflicting tags, please add only the relevant one.

Comment: You want to add a COLUMN.  There is no such thing as "vectors" in a SQL database.

Comment: You shouldn't store actual ages in your table. People tend to become older every year, and your data will soon be out of date. Have a computed column, or view, instead.

Comment: @jarlh I know it is not appropriate, but that's the task I have to perform. Just think as a general column that I have created using a SELECT and then I need to add it to the starting table. Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: @Mary: you need to tell us which database you use. Date functions are highly vendor-specific, so there is no "generic" answer to your question.

Comment: @GMB Thought they are very much relevant since I am using these programs to complete the task, especially PostGreSQL. I am learning to use different programs.

Comment: @GMB that's the database I am using. I have created it, I am a new self-learner of SQL and I am trying to execute basic tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against storing that derived information in the table itself - ages do change over time, so maintaining the information will be tedious.

You can, instead, create a view. In Postgres, you can use date function `age()`, which returns an `interval` that represents the date difference, and then extract its year part:

```
create view myview(name, dob, age) as 
select
    name,
    dob,
    extract(year from age(dob))
from mytable
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to do it without creating a virtual table based but an actual table that I can store and open again? I am not sure if i can do it with virtual table based

Comment: @Mary: well, you can change `create view myview ...` to `create table mytable2 ..`. But I would not recomment that, as explained in my answer. The age is a *derived* column, ie a column whose value can be infered from other columns in the table - and it changes over time, so you don't want to actually store it. It is much better to compute it on the fly (so does the view).